# How to change default icons in mule while developing custom connector?

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

As I am working with the latest devKit (version 3.9.0). @Icons option is not available in the same. So is there any other way to change default icons in `mule` while developing custom connector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created two folders inside the icons folder i.e theme.light and theme.classic and each should have as per following:

- theme.light:

  - connectorname-connector-large.png (pixel: 26x26)
  - connectorname-connector-small.png (pixel: 16x16)
- theme.classic:

  - connectorname-connector-large.png (pixel: 48x32)
  - connectorname-connector-small.png (pixel: 24x16)

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check in the package explorer in studio for a folder call "icons". Inside this folder you will find 2 images.

DevKit will use icons with the following syntax:

```
Small: {connectorName}-connector-24x16.png
Large: {connectorName}-connector-48x32.png
```

NOTE: check the size of your images

After this you can re install the connector.

Comment: thank you for reply. It didn't worked but by this i got some idea and I tried created two folders inside the icons folder i.e theme.light and theme.classic and each should have as per following:
 theme.light:
       connectorname-connector-large.png  (pixel: 26x26)
       connectorname-connector-small.png  (pixel: 16x16)
 theme.classic:
       connectorname-connector-large.png  (pixel: 48x32)
       connectorname-connector-small.png  (pixel: 24x16)
It worked for me..

Comment: I just gave you the standard way of changing the icons as in your question what not specified that you have 2 themes.  would you mind to accept the  answer as valid for the future users reaching this post?